# DateTimeFormatter

Tags: windows-8, globalization, winjs

if I run the following:

```
var newdate = new Date();
var dt = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("shortdate");
var date = dt.format(newdate);
```

I get back something like this 10/14/2012 which is fine, however if I throw that into a url for WinJS.xhr  it changes it to ?10?/?4?/?2012

Sample code for service call

```
var urlAddress ="http://www.communitymegaphone.com/ws/CMEventDS.svc/GetEventsByDistance?Lat='" + mapCenter.latitude + "'&Lon='" + mapCenter.longitude + "'&Dist=" + eventsByDistance + "&$filter=(starttime%20gt%20datetime'" + date  + "')&$orderby=starttime%20asc&$format=json";

WinJS.xhr({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlAddress
    }).then(processSuccess, processError);
```

If I use plain old javascript datetime everything works fine.

Did I miss a setting somewhere?  I have also tried changing the encoding of the url to different formats with no luck.

Comment: Hey Chad...can you edit your question and show a bit more of the code in question? Is there a reason that you're using DateTimeFormatter in the first place, rather than just using the JavaScript date functions?

Comment: using the DateTimeFormatter because it is there while I was playing with the Windows 8 html/js SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTimeFormatter is specifically intended to be user facing. When you create a url, you are no longer user facing, but backend facing. You need to use a standard date format for that (like iso 8601), not one that adjusts to the language of the user. The characters identified by the question marks are left-to-right and right-to-left marks that ensure the string appears correctly even in embedded content.

Answer (score 0):

When you're building a URL like this, the date needs to be expressed as a string.

I'm not sure why the formatter isn't returning the right string, but things like that sometimes indicate a mismatch in encoding between input and output.

I'd say that sticking with JavaScript datetime would probably be the way to go here, unless you really need the DateTimeFormatter for some specific reason.